# convert minutes into hours and minutes with classic asp

Tags: function, asp-classic

I would like to convert minutes into hours and minutes with classic asp

Example:

90

would

1 hour and 30 minutes

How would I do this in classic ASP

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
function toHourMin(minutes)
    hours = minutes \ 60
    minutes = minutes mod 60

    toHourMin = hours & iif(hours=1," hour"," hours") & " and " & minutes & iif(minutes=1," minute"," minutes")
end function

function iif(condition, truepart, falsepart)
    if condition then
        iif = truepart
    else
        iif = falsepart
    end if
end function
```

Note that this will return output like:

```
0 hours and 0 minutes
```

If that isn't desired behaviour, you should state what should happen when you pass in differing (smaller) amounts of time.

Passing in `90` will return what you asked for:

```
1 hour and 30 minutes
```